# integral equality with a Laplace operator.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Lt H and F be holomorphic.

I need to show that F H_x + F H_y = F_x H + F_y H .

I got this equality while trying to prove that two area integrals equal each other, now am stuck.

Comment: 1) General remark : it is likely that Cauchy Riemann equations are the key BUT, PRIOR TO THAT 2) Your notations doesn't look consistant. What do you mean by $H_x$ The derivative with repect to $x$ ? But you have first to separate the real part and the imaginary part of $H$. For example if $H(z)=z^2$ can you say us what would be $H_x$ for you ?

Comment: Partial derivatives are well defined for complex valued functions.

Comment: This is false. Take $F(z) = z, H(z) \equiv 1.$